# Add remove() method to DAO

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, dao, crud

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.developer.com/java/web/integrate-objectdb-into-your-jpa-based-java-web-app.html), which is the easiest Java EE web app using JPA I found on the net after weeks of searching, and I'd like to add a remove method to the DAO but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Here the code I've added to the DAO class:

```
Player player = em.find(Player.class);
em.remove(player);
```

Is it possible to add CRUD functionality? I want keep the code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible and you already have one half of that code, so it shouldn't be so difficult to create a method which does that:-) Just put this in your bean

```
public void removePlayer(Long playerId) {
    Player p = em.find(Player.class, id);
    em.remove(p);
}
```

Try to read something about JPA, it's no so hard to learn(unless you go really deep) and you are asking here something what you could have googled in two minutes:-)

Comment: Thank for reply fast. Any chance to add an edit() option and am done.

Comment: edit is actually the same, just call merge instead of remove on EntityManager. Like I said, try to google little bit next time:-)

Comment: Woow thank you very much, I often search on Google before posting but sometimes, it's just that I dont know how to google it... however, this time I made an effort to find something here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/EJB3/UsePersistenceContextannotationtoLinkPersistenceContext.htm . Thank you again.

Comment: hmm this of topic, is there a way to send you PM, I really apreciate your help and need someone to help me sometimes... Thanks for your undestanding.

Comment: What is PM?But if you like my answer, then you can either upvote or accept it (or even both:-))

Comment: Hi, By PM i mean Private Message. I can't upvote as I dont have 15 reputation yet.